# Which way is better to upload the package in Perl only through require method?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have general question: What is the difference between below code?

Code 1:

```
BEGIN {
push @INC,"/usr/local/bin/";
}
require "package.pl";
```

Code 2:

```
require  "/usr/local/bin/package.pl";
```

Which one is better?

Comment: It's probably *better* to make a ‘proper’ Perl module of your code.

Comment: @Biffen thnx for ur reply I agree with ur point but I don't want to create a package and I have condition to use through only "require" that particular time which one is better method in above?

Comment: Suppose I use 'require' to upload a package which one is a better method between Code 1 or Code 2

Comment: Firstly, `require` doesn't *upload* a package (for any definition of package, whatever yours is). Secondly, what does ‘better’ mean? Faster? More fail-safe? Easier to read?

Comment: I think you need to learn more about require and use

Comment: @Biffen means Faster?

Comment: @user2932003 Is that a question? Anyway, the difference in speed would be negligible.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not doing anything of the sort. Loading something from `/usr/local/bin` as if it were a module is asking for future pain and brittle code.

Why not instead use a module? A module is a lot like a perl script, but it's designed and built to be imported and used in other scripts. Anyone messing with it in future will therefore take due account of this (hopefully - but at least they've got a chance, where importing a random script from a `bin` directory has no chance).

It's quite easy - a package looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package MyPackage; 

sub do_something {
    print "Done something\n"; 
}
1;
```

Save as 'MyPackage.pm'.

Then 'load it' using:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use FindBin;
use lib $FindBin::RealBin . "/modules"; 
use MyPackage;
```

Really very simple, and not as prone to breaking.